# TYPO3 9.5 Form Extension: Cannot submit Form - hash error

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-9.x

When i create a form with the new TYPO3 form extension I cannot submit any form. I get this error:

`[ALERT] request="d1d0c672bfd14" component="TYPO3.CMS.Frontend.ContentObject.Exception.ProductionExceptionHandler": Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20190110160255465e0dc7 - {"exception":"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Security\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentForHashGenerationException: A hashed string must contain at least 40 characters, the given string was only 10 characters long.`

Full Log: https://pastebin.com/QeHHp8Ei

I've followed the instructions from here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/QuickStart/Index.html

Any help would be great. Otherwise I have to switch back to the legacy form extension.

Comment: Please turn on a proper error handling and show us your stack trace. If it does not feel right for you to do this over here in public, you can create an account for TYPO3 Slack (see https://my.typo3.org/index.php?id=35), join the #ext-form channel and post your stack trace over there.

Comment: @BjörnvonTRITUM I've added the Link to the full log. Any ideas what the error could be?

Answer (score 0):

The 9.5.9 Version of the Typo3 built-in Form extension seemed buggy (maybe this affects other 9.5.x versions too). I guess the required actions haven't been made non-cachable in the plugin configuration. I have replaced the forms directory in the sysext folder with a newer version (forms from Typo3 9.5.13), saved the form again, cleared all caches and now the extension works without the error for me. Hope this helps anyone stuck at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this configuration to the global configuration in TYPO3:

`[FE][pageNotFoundOnCHashError]= 0`